# How to upgrade Solidity version in geth or ethereum private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have built my private blockchain of ethereum and i'm curious to know that how can i upgrade to new version of solidity within geth so that we also can develop smart contract on newer version as ethereum do.

Thanks

Comment: Why should GETH care about your solidity version? It takes bytecode as input. That bytecode can be the compilation result of just about anything (so long as this result is a legal bytecode).

Comment: Thank You, I got the answer. I was confused in this but as i  just see the source code of geth and your answers seems that it clear my question.